# Selenium, how to check if proper request was sent after click

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, bots

My Selenium program needs to click several buttons fast as possible, however I'm not sure if proper requests are being sent.

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//input[@name="basketAply"])[1]'))).click()
 WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//input[@name="basketAply"])[2]'))).click()
 WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//input[@name="basketAply"])[3]'))).click()
 WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//input[@name="basketAply"])[4]'))).click()
 WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//input[@name="basketAply"])[5]'))).click()
 WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//input[@name="basketAply"])[6]'))).click()
```

Now if I put sleeps between each line, I can clearly check the code working, because the web site sends back success alert pop-ups for each line.

However, if I run the code without any sleep, all six lines get executed before the success alert pop-up. And only one success alert appears after six lines of execution. I'm not sure if this is because web browsers(I'm using Chrome) cant show multiple alerts or because only the first request was made.

I can't check the program's real result because it's not the application period for the thing I am trying to apply for.

```
<input name="basketAply" type="button" class="button_nav" onmouseover="this.style.color='#000000';" onmouseout="this.style.color='#547585'" value="신청" onclick="javaScript:actBasEvent('3187')" style="color: rgb(84, 117, 133);">
```

This is the full html for one of the buttons, and I think checking if `javascript:actBasEvent('3187')` was actually executed, could help. Is there anyway I could check logs for executed Javascripts?

Or is there any other way to see if all the requests were successful?